# mongoose find and return res.status.json

Tags: node.js, json, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I'm developing an API that shows the bulletin boards list.

And it also shows one of the latest posts at the same time.

In controller I coded like this

```
exports.boards_get_all = (req, res, next)=>{
    Board.find()
    .exec()
    .then(boards=>{

        res.status(200).json({
            count: boards.length,
            boards: boards.map(board=>{

                    return {
                        board: {
                            id:board._id,
                            name: board.name,
                            order: board.order
                        },
                        post : Post.findOne({boardId:board._id})
                        .exec()
                        .then(posts=>{
                           console.log(posts)
                           return posts;
                        }
                        )
                }
    })
   })
  })
}
```

I use findOne() and try to return what Post found

but return post didn't work. just return empty value.

result :

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "boards": [
        {
            "board": {
                "id": "5eb23f1fed38dc5dfc2debfd",
                "name": "QnA board",
                "order": 1
            },
            "post": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

I think I took the wrong approach about using findOne()...

I want to get result like this

```
    {
        "count": 1,
        "boards": [
            {
                "board": {
                    "id": "5eb23f1fed38dc5dfc2debfd",
                    "name": "QnA board",
                    "order": 1
                },
                "post": {
                      _id: 5eb364a27989ab6f414fcdb1,
                      userId: 5eb2aad669738d67b5497f3a,
                      boardId: 5eb23f1fed38dc5dfc2debfd,
                      type: 1,
                      title: 'this is a latest post in QnA board',
                      content: 'Sample content',
                      like: 0,
                      comment: 0,
                      view: 1,
                      date: 2020-05-07T01:30:10.957Z,
                      thumb: 'pic url',
                      __v: 0
                    }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The post is `{}` because the `res.status(200).json()` is executed and returned before the `findOne` callback returns a value.

To fix this, you need to get the post documents from the database before calling `res.status(200).json()`.